# How do I remove the last child of hr in a repeated row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**I am trying to find the most effective way to remove the last two child or last two hr in a repeated row. Please see image and code below. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks!**

In this image I want to remove the last child hr.
In this image I want to remove the last child hr.
[image: In this image I want to remove the last child hr.]

Below is my Jquery:

```
$('.updates-list').find('.row:last').removeClass('.hr_style2');

$('.promo-list').children('.col-lg-12').last().removeClass('.hr_style2');
```

CSS:

```
.hr_style2 {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.promo-list .row:last-child .hr_style2{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="promo-list">
                <div class="other-updates text-center">Other Updates</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="updates-list clearfix">
                                <div id="views-bootstrap-grid-2" class="views-bootstrap-grid-plugin-style">

                                    <div class="row">
                                            <div class="updates-inner-list col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

                                                <div>        <span><a href="path">
                                                <img typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/homepage/home-bg.png" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                                    <div class="updates-title"><a href="#">5 secrets to packing light for out-of-town trips</a></div>
                                                    <div class="updates-details"><p>As soon as vacation season rolls in, people start making plans for out-of-town trips. But before they can enjoy a grand vacay, they first have to conquer…  <a href="#" class="views-more-link">Read More</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <hr class="hr_style2"></span>  </div>         
                                                </div>
                                        </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="updates-list clearfix">
                                <div id="views-bootstrap-grid-2" class="views-bootstrap-grid-plugin-style">

                                    <div class="row">
                                            <div class="updates-inner-list col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

                                                <div>        <span><a href="path">
                                                <img typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/homepage/home-bg.png" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                                    <div class="updates-title"><a href="#">Comfort meets Nostalgia, Divine, and the Magical</a></div>
                                                    <div class="updates-details"><p>Urban comforts enhanced by retro-chic details are making newly opened Summit Hotel Magnolia (SHM... <a href="#" class="views-more-link">Read More</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <hr class="hr_style2"></span>  </div>         
                                                </div>
                                        </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>          
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="updates-list clearfix">
                            <div id="views-bootstrap-grid-2" class="views-bootstrap-grid-plugin-style">

                                <div class="row">
                                        <div class="updates-inner-list col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

                                            <div>        <span><a href="path">
                                            <img typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/homepage/home-bg.png" alt="">
                                            </a>
                                                <div class="updates-title"><a href="#">5 secrets to packing light for out-of-town trips</a></div>
                                                <div class="updates-details"><p>As soon as vacation season rolls in, people start making plans for out-of-town trips. But before they can enjoy a grand vacay, they first have to conquer…  <a href="#" class="views-more-link">Read More</a></p>
                                                </div>
                                                <hr class="hr_style2"></span>  </div>         
                                            </div>
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="updates-list clearfix">
                            <div id="views-bootstrap-grid-2" class="views-bootstrap-grid-plugin-style">

                                <div class="row">
                                        <div class="updates-inner-list col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

                                            <div>        <span><a href="#">
                                            <img typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/homepage/home-bg.png" alt="">
                                            </a>
                                                <div class="updates-title"><a href="#">Comfort meets Nostalgia, Divine, and the Magical</a></div>
                                                <div class="updates-details"><p>Urban comforts enhanced by retro-chic details are making newly opened Summit Hotel Magnolia (SHM... <a href="#" class="views-more-link">Read More</a></p>
                                                </div>
                                                <hr class="hr_style2"></span>  </div>         
                                            </div>
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>          
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please show a _proper_ [mre] of your issue. We don’t want to have to _guess_ what HTML structure you are operating on here.

Comment: Hi, I already added my html. Thank you!

Comment: you don't need to remove them but you can hide them using few tricks, check the duplicate